# How to overcome issue with array key called “length” jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, magento2

I don't know if this is a common issue, but using Magento 2, when the attribute name is `length`, it gives me this error:

> RangeError: Invalid array length

```
var self = this;
if (self.attributeNames == null) {
    self.attributeNames = [];
    self.attributeNames['category_names'] = 'Category';
    $.each(this.availableFilters, function(index, item){
        self.attributeNames[item.attribute_code] = item.frontend_label;
    });
}
return self.attributeNames;
```

Here `item.attribute_code` is dynamic which comes from Magento attributes. So when I create an attribute as `length`, my code was:

```
self.attributeNames[length] = Length;
```

which leaves me with the above error when I use it.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: In your final code snippet, the word 'length' is incorrectly spelled and neither is it quoted.

Comment: Obviously variable `Length` is not a positive number >= 0. But you are not showing what it is from so what help you expect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the third line you should assign an empty object (not an empty array) i.e. `self.attributeNames = {}`. With arrays you can add new items using `push` method and assign values to the existing items (indexed by numbers) only. With objects you can add any particular field in runtime like you did in the forth line.

Comment: This is because in Javascript array are standard array (only numbers), if you want to use a Javascript object as a key-value map you need an object. Note that this is different in PHP, guess that's where OP confiusion come from.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it had a decent explanation of why. The comment by @Walfrat now does some of the explaining, but a good answer should provide more than a single line of 'do this'.

Comment: @PeterB better now?

Comment: Thanks, although I was hoping for a bit more of along the line of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length), which explains why and how `length` is a special property for array-objects in javascript. And that for this question, by using `{}` instead of `[]`, the `length` property can be used freely again.

Comment: @PeterB if you have so great idea what the answer should be submit your answer, please